# How to boot in bios on the lenovo y500?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

Everywhere I look I cannot find anywhere, that give a guide on how to boot into the bios on the y500. Can anyone help? I have been looking for hours.

Answer (score 4):

The [Lenovo Y500 User Guide](https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/y400_y500_ug_en.pdf), on p. 26, states the following:

"**BIOS setup utility**

What is BIOS setup utility?

The BIOS setup utility is ROM-based software. It communicates basic computer information
and provides options for setting boot devices, security, hardware mode, and other
preferences.

**How can I start the BIOS setup utility?**

To start the BIOS setup utility:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Press the *Novo* button and then select BIOS Setup."

Answer (score 3):

Just press F2 continuously when you start your computer (when you see the Lenovo's logo).

Source: I'm using Lenovo Y500. :)

Comment: It turns to the Boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

**Lenovo Yoga 500 and Windows 8.1**
in order to go to BIOS/UEFI Firmware 
Settings->
Change PC Setting->
Update and Recovery->
Recovery ->
in Advanced Startup click restart now
-- After Restarting:
Troubleshoot->
Advanced Options->
UEFI Firmware Settings->
and then you directly go to BIOS

If you don't find the option UEFI Firmware Settings in Advanced Options then the only way is the Novo button after shutting down(other Lenovos)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using annoying Novo button, just pres **Fn + F2** button combination continuously after restarting the PC. Actually, most people who has got the same problem looks for a solution which **does not include the use of Novo button** as indicated on [Yoga 500 - How to enter BIOS?](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-500-How-to-enter-BIOS/td-p/2228200). Hope this helps...

Comment: Confirming, this works. (well, it worked on my Yoga 500...)

Comment: @DavidBalažic I am happy that it solved the problem :) Thanks for feedback...

Answer (score 1):

On some of these Y500 Yoga netbooks, the Novo button is not a button at all, it is a small hole next to the power switch, with a horseshoe sign next to it.
All you do is to power off the netbook.  Then push into the hole with a paperclip once and it will power on and boot into a multichoice screen, which will allow  you to select boot device, or to enter BIOS/UEFI and make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the laptop is plugged in and charging before you press the NOVO button otherwise nothing will happen! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to where says click and you will get to BIOS setup but it never gets there.

Place a static or rubber mat, tablecloth, or towel on your work surface.
Place the laptop on top bottom up.
Unscrew the bottom, DISCONNECT THE PC BATTERY, pop out the CR2032 button battery,
check the voltage if you have a meter (>3.0 volts),
short the top and botton contacts in the black battery holder.
BIOS / UFEI is now set to defaults.

Replace the button battery, connect the PC battery, flip the PC upright,
press and hold the NOVO button for 4 seconds, release, and select BIOS SETUP. Voila!

No Novo button? Follow one of the other insructions above.
When youv'e made your changes, turn it off and replace the bottom cover.

FACT: Calling US or Mexico Lenovo support will NOT get you an answer.
My first "PC" was an IBM 1130 in 1970.
A "bug in the machine" was caused by something, usually a bug keeping the magnetic donuts in the memory from changing position causing a "stuck" bit.